# integrating the Azure Search Service with Sitecore 8.1 Update 3

Tags: azure-search

We are integrating the Azure Search Service with Sitecore 8.1 Update 3. However, could not find any thorough documentation for the same and are having difficulty performing the steps mentioned in here  https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/search_and_indexing/configure_azure_search  It is mentioned in this link to enable the Azure search files, but we cannot find those in our Sitecore instance. Can you please help us with this integration? My major concern is whether the Azure Search is compatible with the Sitecore 8.1 Update 3 or not?

Any assistance in this regard is highy appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure Search was introduced on Sitecore 8.2 Update 1 version, so it doesn't support any version of 8.1 
More details you can find here: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/549969

[image]